# Python: Need help in getting a sum from 2 randomly set numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I've been trying to get list1 and list2 to add up together, I kind of want something like this, "n + n = sum" sorry if I sound dumb, this is my first piece of code.

> n represents the set randomly generated number from A to F

```
# import random
import random


a = 100
b = 50
c = 10
d = 200
e = 100
f = 20

# prints a random value from the list
list1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
print(random.choice(list1))
list2 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
print(random.choice(list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to print out what you want. Before that, store the randomly chosen numbers into variables.

```py
import random

a = 100
b = 50
c = 10
d = 200
e = 100
f = 20

list1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
num1 = random.choice(list1)
list2 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
num2 = random.choice(list2)

print(f'{num1} + {num2} = {num1 + num2}')

# Output (example)
# 100 + 10 = 110
```

Note that your code can be simplified as:

```py
import random

nums = [100, 50, 10, 200, 100, 20]
num1, num2 = random.choices(nums, k=2)

print(f'{num1} + {num2} = {num1 + num2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pick two distinct indexes from the list, the sample() function from the random module would be better than choice().  You also don't need to make two identical lists.

```
import random
num1,num2 = random.sample([100, 50, 10, 200, 100, 20],2)
print(num1,"+",num2,"=",num1+num2)
```

This could give 100 + 100 = 200 (because 100 is present twice in the list but not 50 + 50 = 100 (because there is only one 50 in the list).

Answer (score -1):

I found this article in a google search

https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-the-sum-of-two-lists-in-python

This may be more complicated than you are looking for but I like it because it has list comprehensions which are unique to python and really powerful when you get used to them.

First you use the zip() function which turns two lists into an object you can use for looping through both lists at the same time.

```
zipped_lists = zip(list1, list2)
```

then you use the list comprehension

```
sum = [x + y for (x, y) in zipped_lists]
```

The list comprehension will take one item from each list (represented by x and y) and then add them together.  The output should be a summed list.

There are probably easier ways...

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This solution gives you a summed string, if that's what you are looking for, instead of just printing the sum which won't allow you to do anything further with it.  It is a little more complex, if you want to know how it's working you will probably need to do some research on list comprehensions.  If you do it will change your life.

Here's a good place to start:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp